# A google-like calendar timeline for React.js

Tags: reactjs, calendar, next.js, timeline

I'm wondering if there's a timeline calendar to display certain events that will happen on it, just like google calendar but for React.js?

I tried searching a lot for this but with no luck.

I just need a library or a component that will take a JSON file with dates and titles and display it on the calendar. That's it. No interactions needed.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: just a google result, don't know if it works but: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule)

Comment: @saeedghotb Thanks for the help, however, I just need some component or library to take JSON with dates and titles and display them on a calendar. that's it.

Comment: Is there any problem that you don't want to write this component yourself?

Comment: @Mahdi I was just wondering if there's a library or something that would do that before putting the time and effort into writing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one  [https://fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/) It has all the requirements that you need,
and here is the npm link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fullcalendar/react

Comment: @Ruby if you got my answer helpful, response or if you got the library, kindly post it

Comment: It will not work properly in the latest nextjs .

Comment: Also their [timeline feature](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view) requires purchasing premium license, so just FYI